# Pandas - row addition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe set:

```
     Date         Amount     Total
  0 2017-02-11     -11.7     
  1 2017-02-08    -110.7    1377.4
  2 2017-02-08      -1.2    
  3 2017-02-07     -11.1    1489.3
  4 2017-02-07       8.3    1500.4
  5 2017-02-03      -5.2    1492.1
  6 2017-02-01     -12.0
```

Since there are datasets where the total amount might be missing, I have to calculate that one myself. The best way I figured might be to search for the latest existing row, that contains a total value with something like

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Date'], ascending=[False])
df[pd.notnull(df.Total)].iloc[0]
```

This will give me:

```
5 2017-02-08      -5.2    1492.1
```

And then use the total value 1492.1 as a base to calculate all the others. 
Is there an easy way of doing this, or do I have to iterate myself through the datasets calculating the totals from the previous/next dates?

EDIT:
The totals should be calculated by using the x's previous total and adding all negative amounts/subtracting all positive amounts until x.

In example, to calculate the total of index 2 (2017-02-08) I would have to take 1377.4 and add 110.7 to it to receive the total of index 2, which then is 1488.1

Comment: How do you calculate the Total?

Comment: You mean the one from the example data list? Or how to actually calculate it?

Comment: Yes. It is not clear where it comes from and, therefore, not clear how to fill in the NAs.

Comment: I'm sorry I just noticed I had the dates upside-down, I fixed that now. The values are read from a CSV file which only contains some total values but not all

Comment: I still do not see the connection between Amount and Total. Why does 1500.4 become 1492.1? Shouldn't it become 1500.4+8.3=1508.7?

Comment: You have to read it from the bottom up: at the end of day 2017-02-03 the total was 1492.1. On day 2017-02-07 there was a transaction of +8.3 which then leads to the new total of 1500.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cumsum and then plus the base number. (df[::-1].Total-df[::-1].Amount.cumsum()).max() gives you the total prior to the last row. you can then add that base to the cumsum results. Also, as your data is added from bottom up, you need to reverse the rows using df[::-1] first.

```
df['Total_New']=df[::-1].Amount.cumsum()+(df[::-1].Total-df[::-1].Amount.cumsum()).max()

df
Out[219]: 
         Date  Amount   Total  Total_New
0  2017-02-11   -11.7     NaN     1365.7
1  2017-02-08  -110.7  1377.4     1377.4
2  2017-02-08    -1.2     NaN     1488.1
3  2017-02-07   -11.1  1489.3     1489.3
4  2017-02-07     8.3  1500.4     1500.4
5  2017-02-03    -5.2  1492.1     1492.1
6  2017-02-01   -12.0     NaN     1497.3
```